# Sprinng 4.X passing variables with @Pathvariable annotation

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, request

I want to pass some variables to my server. I did it this way, like shown in the example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
public class RelativePathUriTemplateController {

@RequestMapping("/pets/{petId}")
public void findPet(@PathVariable String ownerId, @PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}
}
```

This works totally fine when I send a request like this:

```
domain/owners/123/pets/123
```

But what I want to do is getting all pets of one owner. This means I dont need/want to pass a pet-ID:

```
domain/owners/123/pets/
```

But then I get an Excpetion that there is no Handler for this request. Is it possible to send a request like this or is it limited by Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a second method:

```
@RequestMapping("/pets/")
public void findPetByOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks - i thought there would be another option

Comment: @TobiasKuess And also you find methods should have a return value.

Comment: yes ofc, It was just a fast example I copied right out of the jQuery Docs